# How to get Date 6 month back from now

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am developing an app for iPhone. I want to calculate 6 month older date from now.

I tried many ways but can't find any good solution. Can someone assist me to do this.

For example today is 21 October then I want date 6 month back from this that is : 21 April

Comment: Dear NSUser, [please mark questions as accepted which have correct answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5370850/nsuser) I see you have not accepted many answers..

Comment: @FahimParkar Sorry for delay.. But when I was accepting I got a message that I can accept it in after five minutes... And I get another work thats Why I missed

Comment: A big Thanks for accepted answers.. This keep SO clean... nothing for points...

Answer (score 3):

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
 NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:[NSDate date]];    
comps.month = comps.month - 6;
NSLog(@"%@",[calendar dateFromComponents:comps]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Working with date, I recommend using [DateTools](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools). To do what you want, just:

```
NSDate *sixMonthsAgo = [[NSDate date] dateBySubtractingMonths:6];
```